# GraphAPI to fetch entire user list with Employeeid

Tags: azure, powershell, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch All users list in Azure active directory with employee id using powershell

When i tried with Mg-User able to fecth expected data but when trying with graphapi not getting the required information, fetching full user list with all parameters

working

```
Get-MgUser -Filter "endswith(mail,'@gmail.com')"
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users (its fetching all user information)
```

Not working -

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=endswith(mail,'@gmail.com')&$orderby=userPrincipalName
```

we wanted to fetch users with their emp id only for particular domain, when using filter also its fetching same data as(https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users)

Please let me know if anything missing here.

Script i am using which is not working, i have tried from postman which works as expected

```
$tenantID = "" 
$clientID = ""
$clientSecret = ""

$AuthBody = @{   
              Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
              Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
              client_Id     = $clientID
              Client_Secret = $clientSecret
                     }
$ConnectGraph = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $AuthBody

$Headers = @{
            "Authorization" = "Bearer $($ConnectGraph.access_token)"
            "ConsistencyLevel" = "eventual"
           }

$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=endswith(Mail,'@gmail.com')&$orderby=userPrincipalName"

$userinfo = Invoke-Restmethod-Headers $Headers -URI $url -Method GET -ContentType "application/json"
```

Answer (score 1):

To fetch  **`employeeid`**  of the users with the particular domain, try the below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=endswith(mail,'@gmail.com')&$orderby=userPrincipalName
```

- Add count=true to the query
- And add  **header**  as  `ConsistencyLevel: eventual`

***I am able to fetch all the user details successfully like below:***

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.count": 4,
    "value": [
        
        {
            "id": "cb70c0b9-00b4-44b4-8a2e-XXXXXXX",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "ageGroup": null,
            "businessPhones": [],
            "city": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2023-03-27T03:44:25Z",
            "creationType": null,
            "companyName": "Hybe",
            "consentProvidedForMinor": null,
            "country": "India",
            "department": null,
            "displayName": "XXX",
            "employeeId": "12345",
            "employeeHireDate": null,
            "employeeLeaveDateTime": null,
            "employeeType": null,
            "faxNumber": null,
            "givenName": "XXXXXX",
            "imAddresses": [],
            "infoCatalogs": [],
            "isLicenseReconciliationNeeded": false,
            "isManagementRestricted": null,
            "isResourceAccount": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "legalAgeGroupClassification": null,
            "mail": "XXXXXX@gmail.com",
            "mailNickname": "ruk",
            "mobilePhone": "+91 91330XXXXX",
            "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
            "officeLocation": "Korea",
            "onPremisesDomainName": null,
            "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
            "otherMails": [],
            "passwordPolicies": null,
            "postalCode": null,
            "preferredDataLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [
                "smtp:XXXX@m365x562XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
                "SMTP:XXXXXX@gmail.com"
            ],
            "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2023-05-27T04:50:08Z",
            "securityIdentifier": "S-1-12-1-3413164217-1152XXXXXXX",
            "showInAddressList": null,
            "signInSessionsValidFromDateTime": "2023-05-27T04:50:08Z",
            "state": null,
            "streetAddress": null,
            "surname": "",
            "usageLocation": null,
            "userPrincipalName": "XXX@m365x56XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
            "externalUserConvertedOn": null,
            "externalUserState": null,
            "externalUserStateChangeDateTime": null,
            "userType": "Member",
            "employeeOrgData": null,
            "passwordProfile": null,
            "assignedLicenses": [],
            "assignedPlans": [],
            "authorizationInfo": {
                "certificateUserIds": []
            },
            "deviceKeys": [],
            "identities": [
                {
                    "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                    "issuer": "M365x56XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "issuerAssignedId": "XXX@m365x562XXXX.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, for some reason its not working in my environment. Its pulling empid but its not pulling users as expeted, its pulling all user details irrespective of the domain specified.

Comment: FYI, i am trying this on B2B where mail & UPN is differnet, but when i tried 

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users

Get-MgUser -Filter "endswith(mail,'@contoso.com')" -Sort "userPrincipalName" -CountVariable CountVar -ConsistencyLevel eventual

Comment: Edited questin and added script i am using, help me if missing something